# how to upload file ftp in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

Getting Connection timed out with flysystem-ftp even when the file appears in FTP. file upload is successful, but immediate after uploading, ftp_fput() times out, regardless of the timeout limit specified

my file system config:

```
        'ftp' => [
            'driver' => 'ftp',
            'host' => 'sftp.test.com',
            'username' => 'test',
            'password' => 'test@123',
            'port' => 21,
            'ssl' => true,
            'root' => 'Final',
            'timeout' => 120,
        ],
```

my code:

```
    $file  = \App\Models\File::query()->first()->name;
    $file = new UploadedFile(Storage::path($file), $file);

    $disk = Storage::disk('ftp');

    $disk->put('s.txt', $file);
```

i throw this error:

"message":"ftp_fput(): Connection timed out",
"line":"163",
"file":"/home/m/project/my_project/tx_test/vendor/league/flysystem-ftp/FtpAdapter.php"`

This seems to be the same as discussed in https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/getting-connection-timed-out-with-flysystem-ftp-even-when-the-file-appears-in-ftp

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, it happens if the connection runs out right after the file transfer or before Flysystem finalises the operation. You can manually close the FTP connection after transferring a file.

```
$disk = Storage::disk(`ftp`);
$disk->put(`s.txt`, $file);
$disk->getAdapter()->disconnect();
```

### Ideas for debugging

1. Try to set `ignorePassiveAddress` to true. Flysystem will use the primary `FTP` server address instead of relying on the local IP.
2. Verify the `SSL` setting. If the server supports `SSL`, set FTPS to true.
3. Check the server for low `ResponseTimeout`.
4. List the contents of directories using the `recurseManually` option. See if it affects the issue.
5. Watch the `FTP` server for network performance issues. You could resolve the issue by increasing the server's configuration.
6. Try rolling back or updating `flysystem-ftp`.
7. Ensure you've opened passive ports on the `FTP server's firewall.

Comment: I can upload my file with filezilla